# Storing datetime in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have some values in mysql `(now())` that I'd like to pull into a numpy array. Once I pull the data from mysql, it is formatted as a list of time like `(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 16, 56, 14), (datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 23, 16, 59, 17),))`.

I can pull other data types into numpy (strings, floats) but fail on this. The dype I'm trying is datetime64 and I get the following:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="x", passwd="x", db="x")
curs = conn.cursor()
numrows = curs.execute("select float, string, date from table")
A = numpy.fromiter(curs.fetchall(), count=numrows, dtype=('float128, a25, datetime64'))
```

And then:

```
Traceback
A = numpy.fromiter(curs.fetchall(), count=numrows, dtype=('i4, a25, datetime64'))
TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

So the problem seems to be that it is expecting a different date format as per http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html . How can I get numpy to accept this data or otherwise manipulate the data before adding it?

Comment: One sure-fire approach would be to `select` the formatted date instead; numpy datetimes can be initialized from ISO datetime strings, IIRC.

Comment: @Sneftel seems tricky. I tried selecting `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')` but it still won't accept that as datetime64. Leads to `ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units`.

Comment: Try giving the type as `datetime64[D]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `datetime64[us]` instead of `datetime64`

```py
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="x", passwd="x", db="x")
curs = conn.cursor()
numrows = curs.execute("select float, string, date from table")
A = numpy.fromiter(curs.fetchall(), count=numrows, dtype=('float128, a25, datetime64[us]'))
```